# The report published at JRS Enterpise Edition does not show the Google Maps component

Tags: google-maps, jasperserver

I've activated a new Google Cloud Platform subscription: trial period is active, billing is properly configured. I've also configured required API's for Jasper Studio: Geocoding, Static and Javascript.
The API KEY is set up in Jasper Studio Pro.

When I edit a map in preview mode, the message "For development purposes only" is displayed, so I can't set map properties automatically.
When I run the Jasper Report HTML preview, the message disappears and I'm able to use the map on my  laptop.
When I publish the report on remote JasperReports Server Enterprise Edition (licensed), the report runs but it's empty and no map is displayed at all.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Jasper Reports requires a section with data.
The map is placed inside summary band.
I added a dataset, a detail band and I placed the dataset fields inside the detail band; next I published again the report and the map was displayed.